# www-data run un-named process

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I have run a server with 2vcpu and 4 GB of ram. my software setup is apache2+php7.0+drupal-7. I'm facing 100% CPU utilization due to the un-named process called [] and is owned by www-data. (screenshot FYR). looking for solution..[click to view top result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHY4d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that it's running as user www-data and it's deliberately un-named, I would guess with high confidence that your server is most likely compromised. Canonical answer here for handling a breached server: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: after some research, I'm using gdb tool for finding a location of the process. **www-data automatically creates the files to /tmp dir. if any possibilities to logging which php file creates this files in tmp directory**

Comment: Take the advice from the link Sven and I posted - ultimately, don't try to salvage it. Nuke the server from orbit and start fresh.